# Word column/text-box/frame/table height same as anchored paragraph, regardless of content

Tags: microsoft-word

**Update:**

After sending this post I realized that columns may not be best idea to achieve this effect. Simply put, I want to have a pragraph/container on the left side with only one line of text (section name) having same height with paragraph on its right. Can I auto size height of a text-box or frame or table with paragraph it's anchored to?

---

I have a paragraph style with 2 columns, with different column widths. Main content will be on right column, left column will only contain section name.

I'd like left column have border. My every attempt to achieve this using frames, text box or table ended up only having horizontal auto resize, not vertical. Which means only one line of bordered section name on the left while column on the right has several lines of text.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
[image: image showing left bordered column with no border right column]

Thanks

Comment: Use a table with two columns and one row. Add a border to the left cell and no border to the right cell.

Comment: I updated my question. I did take secreenshot of example above by doing what you recommend @DavidPostill but this Word document will be used with conjunction of add-ins. We perefere to use content controls will be added in document (for add-in to work) in paragraphs, not in tables.

Comment: I guess I'll end up using table.